# JComboBox set start index to "1"

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Is there an easy way to set the start index of a `JComboBox` to "1" or "2"?
If you start your application the index is normal set to "0" but I want to start with index "1" instead.

Edit:

```
JComboBox variableBox_1 = new JComboBox();
for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getVariableNames().size(); i++) {
    variableBox_1.addItem(dataModel.getVariableNames().get(i));
}
JPanel comBoxPanel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JLabel comBoxLabel1 = new JLabel("X:");
comBoxPanel1.add(variableBox_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
comBoxPanel1.add(comBoxLabel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
optionPanel.add(comBoxPanel1);
variableBox_1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    sp.setVariableNumberX(variableBox_1.getSelectedIndex());
    hg1.setVariableNumber(variableBox_1.getSelectedIndex());
    sp.setXvariableText(dataModel.getVariableNames().get(variableBox_1.getSelectedIndex()));
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`JComboBox#setSelectedIndex(int anIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex(int)):

> Selects the item at index `anIndex`.

For selecting an item in the list, use [`JComboBox#setSelectedItem(Object anObject)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Does the OP want this or a one-indexed combo box? It's still unclear to me.

Comment: I want to set the start value. When I start my program there is an function to add the items to the JComboBox and than the there is no of that items set at the beginning. I want to set one of the added items. The Program is to plot data from array Lists, there are some different variables and the comboBoxes arte there to choose the variables. So when I start the Programm and there is no variable set I can't see the plot so for example i want to set variable 1 on start.